# count rows with group by and having count (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I'm having trouble with query in PostgreSQL . Here is example data from my table `imgs_tags` :

```
img_id | tag_id
   1        2
   1        3
   2        2
   2        3
   3        2
   3        3
```

I had tried :

```
select count(img_id) from imgs_tags where tag_id IN(2,3) group by img_id having count(tag_id) = 2
```

and it returns as below :

```
count:
  2
  2 
  2
```

But I want it to return `count = 3` . How can i fix it ? Thanks

Comment: Looks like 3 rows ... Can you edit the question and add your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write like this:

```
select count(*) from (
select img_id
from imgs_tags 
where tag_id IN (2,3) 
group by img_id
having count(tag_id) = 2
) t
```

or if you want to do some further operation with this data then better use `Common Table Expression (with clause)` like below:

```
with cte as (
select img_id
from imgs_tags 
where tag_id IN (2,3) 
group by img_id
having count(tag_id) = 2
) 

select count(*) from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subquery like this

```
select count(*) from (select count(img_id) from imgs_tags where tag_id IN(2,3) group by img_id having count(tag_id) = 2) as temp_img_tags;
```

`returns` **3**